# How to create single JSON for all matching results?

Tags: php

I am fetching data from the database, and while I'm fetching, I check for each result if it matches certain criteria, if it does, I want it to add the row with all the details as a new object inside the same JSON, so that I end up with a single JSON that holds all the matching rows

```
while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if (matching criteria){
        //add row to the JSON
    }
}
```

Right now I can add each row and echo it, but it overwrites the previous row:

```
while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {        
    if (matching criteria){
         $firstColumn = $result['firstColumn'];
         $secondColumn= $result['secondColumn'];
         //more columns if necessary. . .
         $myObj->firstColumn = $firstColumn ;
         $myObj->secondColumn= $secondColumn;       
         $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
         echo $myJSON;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pseudocode: `$array = []; while(something) {  $array[] = [some other array or object]; }; echo json_encode($array);`

Comment: by using array over and over, it won't overwrite the previous data written to it? I'm quite a beginner sorry, would love to see more than a pseudo code because I'm having hard times with it

Comment: Nope, `$array[] =` adds as a new item to the end of the array.

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: It would be better if *matching criteria* was part of the SQL as it would only include rows your interested in.

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to add `[]` to `array[]`, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use PDO::fetch_object for ever row and add them to assoc array/another object and then use the json_encode on it.

something like (pseudocode not tested) it will create json array with object for every row:

```
$out = [];
while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
{
    if(matching){
        $out[] = $result;
    }
}
echo json_encode($out);
```

Comment: How does this use the matching criteria?

Comment: @Nico Haase sorry I've missed the if to check matching criteria, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Try this way create a array assign value to that array with myObj Data and after get collection of array convert into Json object

```
$data = array(array());
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {        
    if (matching criteria){
         $firstColumn = $result['firstColumn'];
         $secondColumn= $result['secondColumn'];
         //more columns if necessary. . .
         $myObj->firstColumn = $firstColumn ;
         $myObj->secondColumn= $secondColumn;       
         $data[i][j]=$firstColumn;
         $j++;
         $data[i][j]=$secondCoulmn;
         $i++;
         $j--;
    }
}
$myJSON = json_encode($data);
echo $myJSON;
```